# What kind of expressions "="?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can you tell me why I get this error?

I don't think that used any kind of expressions "=" ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  
            CASE WHEN @SortType = '1' THEN mt.Ad END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SortType = '2' THEN mt.Ad END DESC,
            CASE WHEN @SortType = '3' THEN mt.Fiyat END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SortType = '4' THEN mt.Fiyat END DESC) AS RowNr, * 
     FROM @MainTable mt
     WHERE mt.Fiyat > @MinPrice AND mt.Fiyat < @MaxPrice
       AND mt.MarkaId IN (CASE WHEN @BrandFilter != '' 
                            THEN (SELECT bf.Data FROM dbo.Split(@BrandFilter, ',') bf) 
                            ELSE (mt.MarkaId) 
                          END )
    ) Result
WHERE 
   RowNr > ((@PageNr-1) * 10) AND RowNr <= ((@PageNr) * 10)
```

SQL Server gives this error ;

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My split function returns multiline table but I wrote `IN` not `=`

Thanks

Comment: I don't think CASE can return a table-value, only scalars

Comment: Could you describe in words *exactly* what you want to happen when `@BrandFilter = ''`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CASE WHEN @BrandFilter != '' THEN` clause expects a single scalar value, but you are calling a UDF that could return multiple rows.

Comment: Why it expects a single scalar value I Used " AND mt.MarkaId IN "

Comment: You take a table of values from the split function, but you then pass it through a `CASE` expression that *expects a scalar value*. The fact that this is surrounded by an `IN` expression is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `CASE` that way. It looks like the condition you're trying to code is this:

```
(@BrandFilter = '' OR 
@BrandFilter != '' AND mt.MarkaId IN (SELECT bf.Data FROM dbo.Split(@BrandFilter, ',')))
```